# Facebook Business SDK for PHP - Unknown Components

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I am trying to access a user via the Facebook Business PHP SDK but I am getting the following error:

`USER_ID` is just a placeholder for my FB ID.

```
FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException
Unknown path components: /USER_ID
```

The code I am using is as follows:

Again the `APP_ID`, `APP_SECRET`, `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`, AND `USER_ID` are all placeholders but are correct in my code.

```
    $api = Api::init(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, USER_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
    $api->setDefaultGraphVersion('v13.0');

    $fbuser =  new \FacebookAds\Object\User(USER_ID);

    die(var_dump($fbuser->getSelf()));
```

This is the first step of what I am trying to achieve, I need to access the ad accounts associated with a user but when I call the following:

```
  die(var_dump($fbuser->getAdAccounts()));
```

I get the same error:

```
FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException
Unknown path components: /USER_ID/adaccounts
```

When call the graph API directly via cURL or the graph api explorer. I get a list of ad accounts as intended, so i am not sure sure what the problem is.

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/USER_ID/adaccounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I have seen some old issues on here relating to the version of the API being wrong, but i have tried both `13.0` and `v13.0` still no luck.

Would appreciate any help as i would prefer to use the SDK then writing my own wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further tinkering, it does indeed look like it's an issue with the version of the graph.

The version needs to be set as `13.0`, not `v13.00`.

Working code to get ad accounts if anybody else has this issue:

```
    $api = Api::init(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, USER_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
    $api->setDefaultGraphVersion('13.0');

    $fbuser = new \FacebookAds\Object\User();
    $fbuser->setId(USER_ID);

    $facebookAdAccounts = $fbuser->getAdAccounts(['id', 'account_id', 'name', 'timezone_name', 'currency']);
```